# Concurrency in Practice - volatile ++

Tags: java, concurrency

In *Concurrency in Practice*, it says you can use volatile variables if

> Writes to the variable do not depend on its current value.

So, if you have a shared, mutable variable `a`, and all threads ever do to it is go `a++` (they don't get the value, they just `++`).

Then according to the quote, you should be able to make it `volatile` even though `a++` is not atomic, correct?

Comment: Isn't a++; equivalent to a = a + 1; ? And if it is so, you have to read a, then write a+1 to a.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, using `++` on a `volatile` variable is *not* threadsafe, because

```
a++
```

is equivalent to:

```
int temp = a;
temp = temp + 1;
a = temp;
```

So the write back to `a` may happen *after* another thread has modified `a` since your thread read it, so `a++`, even if `a` is volatile, is *not* threadsafe.

You can use [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html), which implements threadsafe atomic incrementation.

Comment: +1 Technicality, but it's only equivalent to that if `a` is an `int`.

Answer (score 6):

a++ reads the value of a, since it's equivalent to

- read a
- increment the read value
- assign the new value to a

So no, you can't safely use a volatile variable in this case.

Answer (score 3):

**- Volatile does the following things:**

- A field marked `volatile`, will have its **value written to the memory immediately**, and **during retiring**, its **value is read from memory**.
- **Prevents caching** of **value** in Thread.

**Eg:**

`a++` **can be interpreted as following:**

**-** Reading of the value of memory location named a.

**-** Incrementing the value.

**-** Writing the newly incremented value to memory location named a.

Now the whole above process is `not` **Thread-Safe,** and `++` (Increment operator) in Java is **not an Atomic Statement.**

**-** Better use `synchronized` keyword or if you don't like using it, go with `AtomicInteger` Class.

Answer (score 1):

a++ is not atomic, it is equivalent to

- retrieving a
- adding 1
- storing the result back into a

Thus, you can still "miss updates", if another thread gets in the way - volatile is not designed to prevent that, that's what "synchronised blocks" and "locks" are for.

The fact a is volatile only affects its visibility amongst threads, as a is not stored in the local cache, so different threads (running on different cores or processors) can immediately "see" its new value.